# modify wordpress search to display author pages

Tags: wordpress

I have been looking around the web but could not find a solution to this problem. Right now the search function in Wordpress - as I understand it - goes through the posts and looks for matching words. That is fine, however I am working on a site right now where I wont have many posts / any posts. I will however have a lot of users - let's call them authors even though they won't be writing anything. I want the normal search to go through the author pages and display results based on what is written there.

Is this possible? I do understand a bit of code but mostly copy of tutorials.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't provide any code attempts i will stick with a plugin solution..

try this

https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-users/screenshots/

Comment: Hey, the plugin doesn't help me. As I said i need to modify the actual wp search to display links to / parts of the author pages instead / in addition to the normal posts